# Integration of spark and kafka, exception in Spark-submit a jar

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

Got a **NullPointerException** when submit a **jar** file that **integrate kafka with spark under ubuntu**. I'm trying to run the code at https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.1.1/examples

I tried to check if installing spark under **Ubuntu** requires set **HADOOP_HOME**; However, HADOOP_HOME is not set, checked carefully the arguments of the jar.

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaKafkaWordCount" --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 --master local[*] --jars ~/software/JavaKafkaWordCount.jar localhost:2181 test-consumer-group streams-plaintext-input 1
```

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getName(Path.java:337)  at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: print full stack trace and line numbers its very difficult to give answer with out that

Comment: I ran this on the terminal, this is only the exception that appears.
I think it is in this line "org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getName(Path.java:337) at "
Is it a problem of hadoop file system?

Comment: ` --jars  /fullpath/JavaKafkaWordCount.jar` try this

Comment: see the mode of  execution here https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17580

Comment: I got the same error:

WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getName(Path.java:337)

Comment: what do you mean its the same error your path is wrong pass full path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your path uri jar is not understandable see [this DependencyUtils.scala#L136](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/DependencyUtils.scala#L136)

```
 /**
   * Download a file from the remote to a local temporary directory. If the input path points to
   * a local path, returns it with no operation.
   *
   * @param path A file path from where the files will be downloaded.
   * @param targetDir A temporary directory for which downloaded files.
   * @param sparkConf Spark configuration.
   * @param hadoopConf Hadoop configuration.
   * @param secMgr Spark security manager.
   * @return Path to the local file.
   */
  def downloadFile(
      path: String,
      targetDir: File,
      sparkConf: SparkConf,
      hadoopConf: Configuration,
      secMgr: SecurityManager): String = {
    require(path != null, "path cannot be null.")
    val uri = Utils.resolveURI(path)

    uri.getScheme match {
      case "file" | "local" => path
      case "http" | "https" | "ftp" if Utils.isTesting =>
        // This is only used for SparkSubmitSuite unit test. Instead of downloading file remotely,
        // return a dummy local path instead.
        val file = new File(uri.getPath)
        new File(targetDir, file.getName).toURI.toString
      case _ =>
        val fname = new Path(uri).getName()
        val localFile = Utils.doFetchFile(uri.toString(), targetDir, fname, sparkConf, secMgr,
          hadoopConf)
        localFile.toURI().toString()
    }
  }
```

In your spark-submit change the args like this

`--jars /fullpath/JavaKafkaWordCount.jar` instead of  `--jars ~/software/JavaKafkaWordCount.jar`

Comment: I got this exception:
ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1560541424000 ms.0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
 at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)..

Comment: this you have to ask  seperate question

Comment: This un supported class will come when you compile with one version and run with another lower version

Comment: Yes, I was checking the compatible versions.
I'm using Scala 2.11.12, kafka_2.12-2.2.0, spark-2.4.3, java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS, spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.3
I don't know which versions to use and which are the compatible?